# How to apply autosave concept in radio button in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to autosave form in angularjs using sessionStorage and it almost achieved it. The data entered in the form should not clear while refreshing that page. But it is not working for the radio button. 
Can anyone have an idea?

my HTML,
The radio button is true in Male as default.

```
<lable><input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="true" ng-checked='user.gender==true'ng-change="save()" />Female</lable>  
 <lable><input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="false" ng-checked='user.gender==false' ng-change="save()" />Male</lable>
```

js file,

```
scope.save=function(){
    sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify($scope.user));
    var xyz= JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
}
```

[Here is the plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/JgjUqEaas8PLGqHE7eof)

Comment: Can you create a plunkr ?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/JgjUqEaas8PLGqHE7eof

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

[Check out this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z3aeYOIyuwnE1VqgKhGF?p=preview)

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
 .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.save = function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify($scope.user));
   };
   $scope.checkSession = function(){
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('user')){
      $scope.user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
    };
  }
}]);
```

I also corrected:

```
ng-checked="user.gender==='true'"
```

Note that `'true'` is now string after `JSON.parse()`

**HTML**:

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="checkSession()">
  <p>Write something in the input field:</p>
  <lable>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="true" name="gender" ng-checked="user.gender==='true'" ng-change="save()" />Female</lable>  
 <lable>
   <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="false" name="gender" ng-checked="user.gender==='false'" ng-change="save()" />Male</lable> 

</div>

<script>
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.save = function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify($scope.user));
      };
      $scope.checkSession = function(){
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('user')){
          $scope.user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
        };
      }
    }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes.. I have tried this method also. But it is not working

Comment: It works for text input field only. It is not working for file upload

Comment: @dijofrancis : 1. Mark it as an answer as it has resolved your question. 2. Create another question with plunkr of `file-upload` and let me know. I'll take a look at it as well.  :)

Comment: @dijofrancis Can't suggest you without seeing your code of file upload